# custom filter for includes - strapi

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

In my strapi, currently, I have content type Footer and It includes multiple links, So I query footer by id as follows:

```
  query Footers($id: ID!) {
    footer(id: $id) {
      id
      head
      links{
          id
          value
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I have another field **expirationDate** to the **Link** type. So, I require to get footer by id( as previous) but, only include links that not expired(date < expirationDate). I wat to give the date as an argument :

```
  query Footers($id: ID!, $date: Date!) {
    //some logic here
  }
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this using the where filter:

```
query Footers($id: ID!, $date: Date!) {
  footer(id: $id) {
    id
    head
    links(where: { expirationDate_gt: $date }) {
      id
      value
    }
  }
}
```